# On IE9 edit mode, paragraph can't be displayed with background-color span

Tags: html, internet-explorer-9, background-color, contenteditable

Below is my HTML source example:

```
<body contenteditable='true'>
<p id='p1'>Paragraph 1</p>
<p id='p2></p>
<p id='p3'><span style='background-color:#f00;'></span></p>
<p id='p4'><span style='background-color:#f00;'>Paragraph 4</span></p>
</body>
```

The body only display three paragraph p1 p2 and p4. The browser doesn't display the p3 paragraph. But it displayed if I add other style in the span. Is it a IE9 bug? Does anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: The content is there; make sure to check your `Developer Tools` in IE9 by pressing `F12`. Try adding some test to the third paragraph, that should fix your problem. Also, you can set that SPAN with `display:block;` and set a width/height to see the red background.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is only a sample of the HTML, but there is a quote missing in the ID of p2

```
<p id='p2></p>
```

which perhaps was meant to be

```
<p id='p2'></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, IE does not like rendering blocks in contentEditable mode that don't have content. You can use the non-breaking zero width unicode character FEFF to force it to render. Just ensure you cleanse it if you are saving the content. Put this within the span: `&#65279;`